# como mostrar la cantidad de números pares e impares de una matriz

Tags: java, matrices, matriz

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El enunciado del ejercicio esta en la foto.

```
package Ejercicios_trabajo_final;
import java.util.*;

public class Ejer_21 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n,m=0, par = 0, impar = 0, n1=0;

        System.out.println("¿Cuantos numeros va ingresar en el 1° arreglo?");
        n = lector.nextInt();
        int M[] = new int[n];
        System.out.println("¿Cuantos numeros va ingresar en el 2° arreglo?");
        n1 = lector.nextInt();
        int N[] = new int[n1];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < M.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese número");
            M[i]= lector.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < N.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Ingrese número");
            N[i]= lector.nextInt();
        } 

        for (int i = 0; i < M.length; i++) {
            if (M[i]% 2 == 0) {
                par = par + 1;
            } else {
                impar = impar + 1;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < N.length; i++) {
            if (N[i]% 2 == 0) {
                par = par + 1;
            } else {
                impar = impar + 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Total numeros pares: " + par);
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Total numeros impares: " + impar);
    }
}
```

Este es el **código** que hice, pero como no se hacer una **matriz**, lo hice con dos vectores diferentes.

Answer (score 1):

estas bien en la parte de calcular si es par o impar , edtas mal en como declarar una matriz la matriz deberia ser
`Int matriz [][]=new int[n][n];` donde n son las dimeciones de la  fila y columna , solo utiliza dos for para recorrer la matriz y  luego mira cada uno de sus elementos si son pares e impares.
Para recorrer la matriz es:

```
for(int i =0;i<matriz.length;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<matriz[i].length;j++){
    }
}
```

Comment: Y como hago para que la persona ingresé los valores de las columnas y las filas y luego poder validar si son pares o impares?

Comment: Fijate que cada for recorre algo de la matriz , uno la fila y otro la columna entonces despues de haberle declarado las dimenciones de la matriz lo único que falra es dentro de los for es matriz[i][j]=lector.nextInt();