# Quiero recorrer la matriz de M * N y solo mostrar los números pares

Tags: java, matrices

- 1. Realice un programa que permita insertar números en una

     - matriz de tamaño M X N, posteriormente
     - muestre la cantidad de números pares de cada fila.
       * Ejemplo: Entrada               Salida
       3 4              4 2 1
       4 6 2 2
       6 7 4 3
       3 6 3 1

     */

````
       Scanner x = new Scanner (System.in);
       System.out.println("Introduze el numero de filas ");
        int M =x.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Introduze el numero de columnas ");
        int N =x.nextInt();
        int matriz [][]= new int[M][N];
        for(int i=0; i<M;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
            matriz [i][j]=x.nextInt();
  ```
````

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Ya nos compartiste el enunciado y un bloque de código. ¿Cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: llena de valores tu matriz luego recorrela evaluando si cada valor%2==0 con eso obtendras los pares,adicional puedes usar un contador de pares con los cuales puedes crear un arreglo donde almacenar esos numeros pares generados  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/369265/como-mostrar-la-cantidad-de-n%C3%BAmeros-pares-e-impares-de-una-matriz

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cual es el problema?

Answer (score 0):

una forma de saber si un número es par o impar es con el operador módulo "%". Este operador te devuelve el resto de la división. Por ejemplo 5 % 2 = 1 ya que el resto de la división de 5 / 2 es 1.

Para conocer la paridad de un número simplemente puedes comprobar que el módulo del número con 2 sea 0 (como el resto de la división es 0, el número es par).

Un ejemplo en JAVA sería:
`

```
/**
 *
 *  supongo que ya existe una matriz definida con nombre "matriz"
 *  de tamaño "m" filas y "n" columnas.
 *
 */

//Recorrer valor a valor la matriz
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        int val_actual = matriz[i][j];
        if(val_actual%2 == 0)
        {
            //Como el resto es 0, este es el caso en el que val_actual es PAR
            System.out.println(val_actual);
        }
        else
        {
            //Como el resto no es 0, este es el caso en el que val_actual es IMPAR
        }
    }
}
```

`

¡Espero que te sirva!

Comment: Aunque se agradece la respuesta, procura no responder a preguntas en donde el OP (autor de la pregunta) solo busca que se le haga la tarea, sin demostrar esfuerzo en resolver el planteamiento, o en donde no se explique cuál realmente es el problema. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.